# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DateFragment

Tags: java, android

I am followed GitHub example for date time picker its working unto 25 but after updating 26 its not working please suggest me on the same the https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker if I add API 25 its running perfect on that code after updating build tool its given exception for the same.

```
public CustomViewPager(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    init(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context)
{
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledPagingTouchSlop();
}

/**
 * Setting wrap_content on a ViewPager's layout_height in XML
 * doesn't seem to be recognized and the ViewPager will fill the
 * height of the screen regardless. We'll force the ViewPager to
 * have the same height as its immediate child.
 *
 * Thanks to alexrainman for the bugfix!
 */
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int height = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height)
            height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);//here error[Logcat Error][1]

    mDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
}

/**
 * When the user swipes their finger horizontally, dispatch
 * those touch events to the ViewPager. When they swipe
 * vertically, dispatch those touch events to the date or
 * time picker (depending on which page we're currently on).
 *
 * @param event
 */
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            y1 = event.getY();

            break;

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           x2 = event.getX();
           y2 = event.getY();

           if (isScrollingHorizontal(x1, y1, x2, y2))
           {
               // When the user is scrolling the ViewPager horizontally,
               // block the pickers from scrolling vertically.
               return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
           }

           break;
     }

     // As long as the ViewPager isn't scrolling horizontally,
     // dispatch the event to the DatePicker or TimePicker,
     // depending on which page the ViewPager is currently on.

     switch (getCurrentItem())
     {
     case 0:

         if (mDatePicker != null)
             mDatePicker.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

         break;

     case 1:

         if (mTimePicker != null)
             mTimePicker.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

         break;
     }

     // need this for the ViewPager to scroll horizontally at all
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

/**
 * Determine whether the distance between the user's ACTION_DOWN
 * event (x1, y1) and the current ACTION_MOVE event (x2, y2) should
 * be interpreted as a horizontal swipe.
 *
 * @param x1
 * @param y1
 * @param x2
 * @param y2
 * @return
 */
private boolean isScrollingHorizontal(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
    float deltaY = y2 - y1;

    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mTouchSlop &&
        Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY))
    {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: did you resolve this error?

Comment: @nicolasasinovich i did not found any solution up to that do you have any solution.